# Recreate the "lighter color" blend mode from photoshop with 2 SDL_Textures

Tags: c, image-processing, sdl-2

I want to create 2 textures and blend them together where the resulting texture takes whichever pixel is brighter between the two textures, similar to the ligher color blendmode in photoshop, is there a way to replicate this using custom blend modes or just a way to directly access the pixel data in a texture or renderer so I can just throw it into a for loop over each pixel? Kee in mind I am using C and SDL2, any help is greatly appreciated.

So far I've tried using SDL_RenderReadPixels and SDL_LockTexture, not knowing that Render read pixels was effectively a screenshot function, and that Locking the texture just stopped any new data from being written to it via a renderer set to target it.

Comment: As in the SDL2 docs [`SDL_RenderReadPixels`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_RenderReadPixels) is VERY slow. You cannot expect real time performance from this function. Often, if you need to do operations like you mentioned you would keep an extra `SDL_Surface` for each texture you need to modify and create a `SDL_Texture` from the result.